# Patterns and why they repeat

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

The squares on a 6x6 chess board are colored black and white. When examining all of the 2x2 blocks of squares that make the chess board, it turns out that at least one 2x2 pattern has to be repeated somewhere on the board....why?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a pigeonhole problem:

> There are $2^4=16$ possible patterns, and $(6-1)^2=25$ possible locations for $2\times 2$ squares on the board. Since $16<25$, at least one pattern must repeat.